# Allowing specific characters using input filter for edittext in android

Tags: java, android

I have an edittext for which i have set an input filter as follows:

```
filter_username = new InputFilter() { 
         public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
                boolean keepOriginal = true;
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(end - start);
                for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {

                    char c = source.charAt(i);

                    if (isCharAllowed2(c)) // put your condition here
                        sb.append(c);
                    else
                        keepOriginal = false;
                }
                if (keepOriginal)
                    return null;
                else {
                    if (source instanceof Spanned) {
                        SpannableString sp = new SpannableString(sb);
                        TextUtils.copySpansFrom((Spanned) source, start, sb.length(), null, sp, 0);
                        return sp;
                    } else {
                        return sb;
                    }           
                }
            }

            private boolean isCharAllowed2(char c) {
                return Character.isLetterOrDigit(c);

            }

}; 

txtusername.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter_username});
```

The issue is i want to do the following changes to the above filter:

1) The first character should **not** be a digit
2) Underscore and dot are the only characters allowed

Can you tell me how to modify the above filter in order to suit my requirements?

EDIT:
I figured out the special characters part by the following changes:

```
private boolean isCharAllowed2(char c) {
                return Character.isLetterOrDigit(c)||c=='_'||c=='.';

            }
```

How do i prevent the first character from being a digit or a period?

Answer (score 0):

[Character.isLetterOrDigit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetterOrDigit%28char%29) check  if the specified character is a letter or digit.so use [Character.isLetter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter%28char%29)  which return `true` if character is a letter otherwise `false`

```
    private boolean isCharAllowed2(char c) {
         if(sb.length()==0)
          return Character.isLetter(c);
         else
          return Character.isLetterOrDigit(c);

    }
```

Comment: But i can accept digits from the second character onwards.I want the validation done on the first character in the edittext.I dont want it to begin with a digit.

Comment: The first character was prevented from being a digit.But after that i can only type letters.

Answer (score 0):

This is the function you should use which does what you requested, building from what you have found already :

1 How do i prevent the first character from being a digit or a period? 
 2 Underscore and dot are the only characters allowed (I assume from your previous edit that you mean letters + digits + underscore + period)

```
private boolean isCharAllowed2(char c, final int position) {
     if(position == 0) // 0 position in your string
      return ! (Character.isDigit(c) || c=='.'); // point 1
     else
      return Character.isLetterOrDigit(c)|| c=='_'|| c=='.'; // point 2
}
```

You call it in your code in the for loop:

```
for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
    char c = source.charAt(i);

    if (isCharAllowed2(c, i)) // this passes the position of the character to your isCharAllowed2 function, allowing you to decide on the filtering there according to the position in the String
      sb.append(c);
    else
      keepOriginal = false;
}
```